# Белая стрелка в Toolbar

Tags: java, android

Как можно добавить белую стрелку или просто любую иконку с левой стороны вместо стрелки homebutton.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988106/custom-home-button-on-actionbar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В своем styles.xml можете написать:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>    </style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/сюда желаемую картинку</item>
</style>
```

Затем в своем активити:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: если нужно для тулбара можно toolbar.setNavigationIcon();